# Add Evolution PPA to Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, ppa, evolution

I'm testing Linux Mint, and I want to add https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/3.28.0-4 to the PPA.

How can I do that? Linux Mint only has 3.18.5.2 as the highest version.

Comment: Don't. *new to Linux* and changing/adding software sources almost never ends well.

Comment: For further reading read https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA .

Comment: Yes it is, MichaelBay, that's how I learn. That's how I grew up with PC since the age of 3. Learning by doing/destroying. I'm not an absolute beginner, mind you. Besides I got Timeshift Snapshots to save me hide.